# Hypothesis testing for rainfall

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I would like to form a suitable hypothesis test with 95% confidence interval to determine which of the months that fall into the Inter-monsoon/monsoon period using the data that I've collected below:

[image]

I was thinking about performing the test something like this for May for instance:

$H_0: \mu = 157.805$

$H_1: \mu < 157.805$

$\alpha = 0.05$

Is this a reasonable way to determine whether may from my observations 2019 is indeed a "inter-monsoon" month? And in that case what statistic would be reasonable to use?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: What rainfall level or range typifies 'inter-monsoon"? What motivates your choice of the hypothesis and alternative for May?

Comment: @BruceET As far as I know there's no exact threshold for what defines a "inter-monsoon". Thus, I've instead taking the average total rainfall for every "may-month" between 1981-2019 and using that as my threshold. The idea I had then were to use my "sample" month may-2019 with 69mm of precipitation and perform a hypothesis test whether we still can say (with 95% conf) that may is indeed a inter-monsoon month. However I'm unsure whether this is a viable approach at all and that's why I came here to ask for help/suggestions. Thanks for the answer